# How to upgrade APC to latest in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, alternative-php-cache

I am running 10.10 version.

I install APC as

```
sudo apt-get install php-apc
```

It gets APC (3.1.3p1) installed. The latest one is 3.1.10 right now.

How can I update to latest one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

1. wait for it to turn up in the official Ubuntu repository, or
2. install [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/) and use PECL/PEAR to install APC but I don't know if that will work for you on Ubuntu

Assuming you have PEAR/PECL installed (and any other necessary dependencies), this should install APC from that repository, which may be at a higher version than the Ubuntu package. It also requires 'libpcre3-dev' to be installed in order to compile properly.

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
sudo pecl install apc
```

Comment: for reference, i just successfully installed via pecl. however, it also requires 'libpcre3-dev' to be installed, otherwise there will be error compling. http://cogo.wordpress.com/2010/07/19/pcre-h-no-such-file-or-directory-when-installing-apc-php-extension/  .  after that, just execute  sudo pecl install apc    to install.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running a released version of ubuntu, you shouldn't expect newer upstream versions of software to be released for that version of ubuntu, only security patches to older versions. You can see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php-apc) that 3.1.10 has been released for a newer release of ubuntu.  You can try backporting that version.

To backport, first you need to add a deb-src line to sources.list that can download source packages for quantal.

```
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main universe
```

Add only that line to sources.list, do not add a deb line, just deb-src.  Then run `apt-get update`.  Then `apt-get build-dep php-apc ; apt-get install build-essential` will install the packages needed for building php-apc, and `apt-get source -b php-apc` should download the source for apc, and build a new .deb in the current directory.  If this works, you can install the deb with somethign like `dpkg -i ./php-apc-$newversion.deb`

However, if you go this route (or pretty much any other route which moves you away from the official ubuntu package for your release), you are on your own for security updates to this package.  And because of this, you should question whether you really need the newer version, or of you just want it because 10 > 3.

Comment: APC 3.1.3 is now nearly 3 years old. I don't see why one should not upgrade. Lots and lots of bugs were fixed even by the step from 3.1.3 to 3.1.4: [Complete Changelog](http://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=APC&release=3.1.10).

Comment: and lots of new not yet discovered bugs could have potentially been introduced.  Or incompatibilities with other software could have been introduced.  This is always the trade-off.

Comment: thanks, should I remove current apc first before attempt install newer? sudo apt-get remove php-apc

Comment: no need to remove first, this will upgrade.